# Is there a scheme compiler can "see" how the syntactic sugar translate to the lambda expression?

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme

There are lots of syntactic sugar:

```
let v=B in E equals ((lambda(v).E) B)
```

can these syntactic sugar be "seen" by the compiler?

the ocaml compiler support -dlambda,the f# compiler support <% %>,but the imformation they give are too complicate:

```
let f x=let a=1 in x+a
```

use "ocamlc -dlambda",got

```
(setglobal A!
(let
(f/80 = (function x/81[int] : int (let (a/82 =[int] 1) (+ x/81 a/82))))
(makeblock 0 f/80)))
```

can't see how the Syntactic sugar change into the lambda,Is there a scheme compiler support this?Thanks!

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with Scheme? 2. Why do you think that `let`-bindings are "desugared"?

Answer (score 0):

*TL; DR: No. Scheme is a minimalistic language with lots of underspecification*

The Scheme reports shows how derived syntax can be defined using `define-syntax`, but there is no requirement that the error message on syntax og runtime errors should be handled. The strongest is usually that an error should be signaled, but there is no further specification beyond that. Eg. if an implementation translates defines in lambda bodies to `letrec` and there is a duplicate name or use of value before `define` is done, chances are you'll get an error about the resulting `letrec` instead of the offending `define` if the macro does not itself error check.

[Racket/DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) software (not the programming language), a language making framework where everything gets dumbed down to kernel-forms that has little to do with any of the supported languages, has made support for tracking the surface language to the expansion as metadata in their syntax tree. With this you can see where the error happens in your code even if the error happens in a much lower level expansion. This is opt-in so if you just make a macro it doesn't automatically do this, but their syntax-rules implementation actually does. Error messages might not make sense so a lot of common errors in Racket macros will be handled [in the macro itself](https://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/index.html).